# Restoring the deleted tag elements from a HTML file using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am reading a HTML file from a folder and delete some unwanted html tags From the HTML file and I should save the modified HTML file.

I have done all the above things using jsoup parsing library. But the problem is if in future if I want to exclude some of the tags from the unwanted list of tags, how should I do that? Because once I deleted the unwanted tags the modified HTML will not have the unwanted content.

Comment: If you're asking how to retro-actively restore something you previously deleted... That's impossible if you don't keep a back-up of the original or if there's not enough information in the altered version to restore the original.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "if i want to exclude some tags from the unwanted list of tags"... Seems like you can just keep 2 copies of the file, modified and unmodified.

Comment: Keep a copy of the original HTML file.

Comment: You all are right.even i thought the same.I posted here to check any other possibility solution to do that

Answer (score 1):

set the original file as filename:

> full_featured_template.html

then parse it with jsoup and save it as

> template_version_1.html

then in future:

parse the original again ans save it as

> template_version_2.html

Comment: Thanks..even I thought the same..I was asking do we have any other solution to acheive that

Comment: use a file versioning thing like git or svn to do rollbacks. Use a database stored template, and thats where my ideas stop